# In 32bit why is the address space limit 2^31?

Tags: windows

In 32bit why is the address space limit 2^31? instead of 2^32?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory so? 2 to the 32nd power is 4 gibi-things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The address space is not limited to 2^31. The address space is 2^32. What you are referring to is that the kernel reserves the upper 2GB leaving applications the lower 2GB.

That's simply an implementation detail of 32 bit Windows. In fact you can run Windows in /3GB mode in which case applications can access 3GB of memory.

Comment: Just some extra info: it's possible to configure that so that Windows only takes away 1 GB. I don't exactly remember the details. Also, I recall seeing somewhere that running under 32-bit WoW subsystem in 64-bit Windows you get more, but I don't remember details of that either. Worth looking into, though. For the OP.

Comment: @Alf that's the [`/3GB` switch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/05/208908.aspx). It does just that. There are no details :)

Comment: @Alf That's the /3GB mode that I mention. Indeed under WoW64 a 32 bit process gets 4GB address, so long as it marks itself as `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE`. It also needs to do that to get 3GB under 32 bit `/3GB`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not.

> The virtual address space for 32-bit Windows is 4 gigabytes (GB) [i.e 2^32] in
>   size and divided into two partitions: one for use by the process and
>   the other reserved for use by the system.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

[Related: Memory Limits for Windows Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)